# Gulp utilities commands ingredients issue with laravel elixir

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, browserify

I`m trying to use laravel elixir in order to compile my js assets and I have the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir/ingredients/commands/Utilities'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel\node_modules\laravel-elixir-browserify\index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I`m trying to use browserify in order to compile the "required" directives for my client side code. Node version is 6.10 and laravel elixir is 6.0.0-15.

My gulpfile.js is looking like this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var browserify = require('laravel-elixir-browserify');

elixir(function(mix){
  browserify.init();
  mix.browserify("bootstrap.js");
});
```

Any help here will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `npm install`

Comment: Yes, but when I run npm install few items are ignored. 

warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.0.0
warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fseven 1.1.1
bble-loader@0.2.2 requires a peer of buble@0.12.0
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@2.2.0 none was installed
npm WARN sass-loader@6.0.5 requires a peer of node-sass@4.0.00 but none was installed
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.4.5 requires a webpack@2.2.0 but none installed

Comment: Try `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install && gulp`

Comment: I receive the same output even after the node_module directory is erased and reinstalled...

Answer (score -1):

You just need to install missing dependencies manually.

For exemple :

`npm install --dev buble@^0.12.0` and rerun `npm install` afterward.